# Python file generates points to plot - RuntimeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

UPDATED:

I would like to plot real time y values generated randomly from Random_Generation_List.py. I have imported the python file and have them in the same folder. The points are only being printed and show only a vertical line on the graph. How do I fix this to make the points plot onto the graph in real time? Like a point every 0.001?

**Random_Generation_List:**

```
import random
import threading


def main():
    for count in range(12000):
        y = random.randint(0,1000)
        print(y)

def getvalues():
    return [random.randint(0,1000) for count in range(12000)]

def coordinate():
    threading.Timer(0.0001, coordinate).start ()
coordinate()

main()
```

**Real_Time_Graph**

```
import time
from collections import deque
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import Random_Generation_List

start = time.time()

class RealtimePlot:
    def __init__(self, axes, max_entries = 100):
        self.axis_x = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axis_y = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axes = axes
        self.max_entries = max_entries
        self.lineplot, = axes.plot([], [], "g-")
        self.axes.set_autoscaley_on(True)

    def add(self, x, y):
        self.axis_x.append(x)
        self.axis_y.append(y)
        self.lineplot.set_data(self.axis_x, self.axis_y)
        self.axes.set_xlim(self.axis_x[0], self.axis_x[-1] + 1e-15)
        self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis

    def animate(self, figure, callback, interval = 50):
        def wrapper(frame_index):
            self.add(*callback(frame_index))
            self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis
            return self.lineplot

def main():

    style.use('dark_background')

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    display = RealtimePlot(axes)
    axes.set_xlabel("Seconds")
    axes.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
    values = Random_Generation_List.getvalues()
    print(values)

    while True:
        display.add(time.time() - start, values)
        plt.pause(0.001)

    display.animate(fig, lambda frame_index: (time.time() - start, values))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

**Error Message:**

> raise RuntimeError('xdata and ydata must be the same length')
>   RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length

Comment: `values` is probably a `list`. You cannot call a function which is a list...

Comment: try to print(values) and check what it returns

Comment: `values` is a `list`--> `values = Random_Generation_List.getvalues()`.

Comment: The complete script is full of errors, once you eliminate one you will run into the next.

Comment: what do you mean @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: @Exprator Values returns a list separated by a comma. (253, 14, 98, 340 etc.) How do I make this not return a list and plot these y values?

Comment: @FJSevilla How do I convert it from a list in order to plot points?

Comment: Do you want to plot each item in the list (x-axis) next to the time (y-axis) with a delay of 0.001 seconds? Why do you multiply by 1000 the list?

Comment: I mean that it's not worth solving this problem with the lists because once that is solved you will run into the next one. On the other hand its not possible to give you a different solution, since it's not clear what this code is supposed to do. So if your inquiry is about how to multiply a list by a value, create a [mcve] for it, or better just google for it. If your inquiry is about getting an animation of random numbers to run, clearly explain your code and the desired outcome in the question.

Comment: @FJSevilla Yes I just want to plot each item in the list with the delay of 0.001 seconds. It does not need to be multiplied by 1000.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The code needs to generate random y values to plot on a real time graph. The random generation of numbers is currently acting as a driver. These numbers need to be plotted against time on a real time graph. I would like the animation of random numbers to run.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is there a way to not return a list and plot the values?

Comment: have you tried `display.add(time.time() - start, values)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes. I get an error about the xdata and ydata being the same length. "raise RuntimeError('xdata and ydata must be the same length') RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length". I do get a graph though with a straight vertical line only.

Comment: okay, so `display.add(time.time() - start, values * 1000)` if your aim was to expand `values` 1000 times, that should do it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am still getting an error about the xdata and ydata being the same length. The graph is not showing time and does not plot any points.